# jquery google link

Tags: jquery, user-interface, google-code

Has anyone got any idea how this google code works?

i got the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>My Google AJAX Search API Application</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=blahblahblah" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1");
   google.load("jqueryui", "1");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="ui-state-highlight">
    hello world
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However the `<div></div>` should display the error box with hello world. but it doesn't show the red background therefor the ui is not working ...

What have i done wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need the stylesheet if you want styling, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

This is the base (grey) theme, [there are others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/jquery-css-download-from-google) (be sure too update the version number!)

Unless you need `google.load` for other things, you can include the scripts directly, it's worth looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208869/what-are-advantages-of-using-google-loadjquery-vs-direct-inclusion-of-ho) for the advantages/disadvantages to using `google.load()`.

Loading them directly would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanx that makes a hell of alot of sense :) unlike googles page... could you help me find the location for the ui? of jquery as there was only the jquery core there ... Also can i not put latest? instead of the version number or something like that i have seen it done before :)

Comment: @Val -Google has a page here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/ for the latest, you can just put `/1/` instead of `/1.4.2/` for the latest version 1, or `/1.4/` for the latest 1.4.x release, make sense?

Comment: it's not necessarily good to use the latest updated one, some of your things may break. I personally like using just 1.8.1 then I'll update when and if necessary.

Comment: @Derek - You can use `1.8`, then you'll get only bugfix releases...in any case, they leave it wide open to the developer to make the decision about upgrades, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

hello world should be displayed, but because the class ui-state-hightlight is nowhere to be found, hello world just appears as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

It works using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

You may also roll your own style here

```
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
```