# Google Loader vs standard <script> tags

Tags: javascript, google-api, cdn, google-cdn

**Google loader**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('jquery','1.7.1');
google.load('jqueryui','1.8.17');
</script>
```

or...

**standard <script> tags**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Which is better and why?

Comment: I think the appropriate question might be, "When do I use Google loader vs when do I use script tags?"

Comment: Possible dupplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208869/what-are-advantages-of-using-google-loadjquery-vs-direct-inclusion-of-h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second solution is better in 99% of uses cases. The first one, you first have to load the Google API script file, then you have to load the jQuery file, which means two HTTP requests (without jQuery UI) where you need only jQuery.

If in your page, you use the Google API to something other than loading jQuery (or another Javascript library), then both solutions *should* be equivalent.

Something "great" with the Google API it's that you can load a *dynamic* version of jQuery, but I've never seen use cases for that...

---

For your information, you could write the script tag in this way

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice I've not set the protocole in the URL. This way, if you're using HTTP then the file will be fetch by HTTP; if you're using HTTPS then it will be fetch by HTTPS.

Comment: I wonder how would IE6/7 react to that technique (//). A lot of the users in the site im working on are still using those old browser versions.

Comment: @andufo you may find informations about it here http://html5boilerplate.com/html5boilerplate-site/built/en_US/docs/html/#the-javascript and here http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: @pomeh, if you want to always load the latest jQuery, [you still don't need the loader](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441412/201952) -- you could just use *//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js*

Comment: @josh3736 don't do that. Firstly, always getting the last version means the jQuery version could change without noticing you, and some code or plugin could break from one version to another. Secondly, this url & this file is only cached for one hour, which means every hour every visitor would have to download again the file. Check the links I provided above and this one too http://paulirish.com/2009/caching-and-googles-ajax-libraries-api/

Comment: I never said it was a good idea, just that you don't need to use the loader library.

Comment: I know that... it was my original answer :)